# JavaScript layout management for MVC/Backbone.js application?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, layout, backbone.js, layout-manager

My web application, written in Backbone.js, has what I call a number of "Modes".
Each mode describes which models and views that are currently active. By changing the mode parameter in the hash (#) I switch between modes and instantiate necessary Backbone models & views.

It seems logical to also describe the preferred layout and inject the container html code on a mode level.

Let's say the mode "PopulationPyramidMode" has a model and 3 Backbone views. The "HeaderView" should take up 30 pixels vertically. The "SidebarView" should take up 200 pixels horizontally and the "CanvasView" should fill moist of the screen and scale on resize events.

To complicate things further, the CanvasView holds a visualization which must be re-rendered on resize, i.e. the x/y-scales must be re-calculated.

**So, what is the best approach to this?**

1) Where should the layout logic go?
- On a separate layoutManager - and in that case how?
- Should each view describe its preferred size etc?

2) How do I inject the necessary HTML/CSS for my layouts and switch between them?

```
<!-- Layout 1 -->
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="canvas"></div>

<!-- Layout 2 -->
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Thanks for any specific hints and also on JavaScript layouts in general!

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud here.  It sounds like you could have one view which manages the layout, but is capable of morphing the layout as needed.  The question is: what triggers the layout change?

You might have a controller which is equipped with the routes and actions for these different modes.  This controller could either hold an instance to this layout view and call a parameterized refresh function.  Alternatively, the controller could trigger an event with the mode change and the view could be set up to listen for it.  Once received, the view would call its refresh function.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion regarding building such applications would be to use the straightforward observer pattern. 
Design your controller in a way that it simply dispatches particular events when the hashtag changes. Have an event map in the controller,that acts as a reference table between events to be dispatched and the urls, better still, you can follow a particular convention regarding the choice of hash parts eg. everytime user navigates to url mydomain.com/#part1/part2 the controller dispatches an event 'evt_part1_part2'. You can use a common dispatch point (which can be a dom element, or a javascript object particularly being used for this very purpose).

Now all your views can listen to this common dispatch point, and if the event matches the one that this view is looking for, you can create the respective environment accordingly through that view. 
This approach definitely helps in compartmentalization of views, leading of more modular and maintainable code.